# Job scheduled with 'Whenever' gem cannot find Rake installation

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rake, rake-task, whenever

Rake tasks succeed when run manually. However, attempting to schedule them with the 'whenever' gem causes them to fail with the following output:

`/Users/[username]/.gem/ruby/2.2.1/gems/bundler-1.10.6/lib/bundler/spec_set.rb:92:in block in materialize': Could not find rake-10.5.0 in any of the sources (Bundler::GemNotFound)`

Rake 10.5.0 is indeed the version that I am currently using. I have added
`env :PATH, ENV['PATH']
env :GEM_PATH, ENV['GEM_PATH']`
to the top of my config/schedule.rb file, but it has not resolved the problem.

Comment: Can you show the code in your schedule.rb?

Comment: `env :PATH, ENV['PATH']
env :GEM_PATH, ENV['GEM_PATH']
set :environment, "development"
set :output, {:error => "log/cron_error_log.log", :standard => "log/cron_log.log"}

every 1.minute do
  rake "namespace:task_name"
end`